# Copying cell value to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have not done a lot of excel VB programming, so have a bit of patience, please.

I have a random number generator in sheet1 cell E5 and everytime I press <kbd>F9</kbd>, I want it to copy the newest value to the last cell in Sheet2, column A.

I worked on this a bit, but I don't think I have something set right.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        thisrow = Target.Row
        lr = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & lr).Value = Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I know that `lr = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` works, when I run it in the immediate window, it pulls the right cell reference.

The man problem is I don't think it is being called properly from my worksheet. Since the value is never copied to the activate worksheet.  I am also not getting any response when I try and put line breaks in.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using two sheets, make sure you give the sheet reference each time you use `.Range`, `.Cells`, etc.

Try `Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & lr).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row).Value`
(of course, this assumes you want that range to be the sheet1 range.

To check this - if you step through your macro (press F8 when in it in the VB editor), and you get to the "pasting" line, if it doesn't page, press `CTRL+G` to open the Immediate Window.  In that window, type `?Range("E"&activecell.Row).Value` to see what the value is for that.